# My contact form is clearing after i click submit one time and only sends empty data to my email using emailjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

So I am fairly new to web development and I am making a contact form for my personal website. I made a contact form before and it worked perfectly but I didnt like the way it looked so I made a nicer looking one and now it doesnt work when I click submit the first time but it still clears the form. It only sends an email if the form is empty and the email it sends is empty.

I'm confident my javascript is correct but im not sure why my form is acting this way.

**HTML**

```
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="name" required>
                        <label for="name"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Your Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="phone" required>
                        <label for="phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i> Phone No.</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" id="email" required>
                    <label for="email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Email Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <textarea id="message" rows="8" required></textarea>
                    <label for="message"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i> Your Message</label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="sendMail()">Submit <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var params = {
        name : document.getElementById("name").value, 
        phone : document.getElementById("phone").value ,
        email : document.getElementById("email").value, 
        message : document.getElementById("message").value, 
    }
    emailjs.send("service_xnukp8n", "template_mv0tglo", params).then(function (res){
        alert("Your form was sent successfully! " + res.status);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Any explanation or tips are appreciated!

Comment: The `js` you have there is the `sendMail` function?

Comment: Any errors in the console? If there’s a syntax error, you should see it, but I noticed `console.log(err)` executes when there is an error sending an email. Check the console

Comment: @ParkingMaster i dont have any errors in the console. when it sends me a blank email it says my success message

Comment: @user3783243 yes my js is just my sendMail function it has worked before with my old form

Comment: I think you should contact EmailJS support. I don’t see anything wrong with your code - And trust me, I have an eagle eye ;)

Comment: On the submit button, try adding this to the onclick event: `event.preventDefault()`, sometimes you have to disable form submit reloads because it will try to make a request to a server once you submit it, but reload because the value is empty

Comment: @ParkingMaster i added the ```event.preventDefault();``` before my params in JS and it works perfectly. now i got to figure out how to clear it after it sends. Thank you so much!